# javascript for matching any number was selected

Tags: javascript

I want to the find possible combinations of *n* digits from a larger set of selected digits, by using JavaScript only.

This is code I found on the internet, but some code is lost:

```
 var nd = true;

 function no_dup(v) {
     nd = !v;
     genfunction();
 }

 function genfunction() {
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("choice");
     var number_set = [];
     var j = 0;
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
         if (x[i].checked) {
             number_set[j++] = x[i].value;
........
........ 
........    
// rest of the code is lost.
```

This is how the page would look:

[image: matching any number]

Comment: So you're looking for all possible combinations of the given numbers while keeping the rule of `XY = YX` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have does almost nothing -- it seems you lost 90% of it.

So, doing it from scratch, here is how I would do it:

```js
function getCombinations(digits, size, prefix = []) {
    if (!size) return [prefix];
    if (digits.length < size) return [];
    return digits.reduce( (acc, dig, i) => 
        acc.concat(getCombinations(digits.slice(i+1), size-1, prefix.concat([dig])))
    , []);
}

document.body.onchange = function () {
    // Get input
    var selectedDigits = Array.from(digits.options)
                              .filter(option => option.selected)
                              .map(option => +option.value);
    var digitCount = +sizes.value;
    // Produce combinations, and turn them into strings
    var combinations = getCombinations(selectedDigits, digitCount)
                        .map(digits => digits.join(''));
    // Output result
    output.textContent = combinations.join(' ');
}
```

```css
select { display: inline-block }
div { clear: left }
.pad option { padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 20px }
```

```html
Hold down Control key to click multiple digits (or drag):<br>
<select id="digits" class="pad" multiple size="10">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
<select id="sizes" size="2">
    <option value=2 selected>2 digits</option>
    <option value=3>3 digits</option>
</select><br>
Combinations: <span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: thankyou very very much trincot your help is very useful BUT i want full code include html code that can display  like my want accord pattern of this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnYjZ.png for let it  perfect display on user mobile screen . just user click to touch  screen to easy select number to combine for gamble local lotto in my country. i wish you will understand me.
thank you in advance. love you forever.

Comment: What you are asking now is too broad. You should continue to try to make the user interface yourself, and if you bump into a *particular* problem (for instance with aligning elements on the page), then ask a *specific* question about that. Note that the downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort", so I am now kindly giving you the task to research and find out how you can make such a user interface ;-) Feel free to ask a new question about a *specific* problem you face in making it work.